# How to disable thumbnail preview for text file

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, thumbnails, previews

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 but I miss one great feature of enabling and disabling preview for text file, so is their any way to do so?

Comment: @Lucio -  I think the problem was this used to be featured by default (e.g. The 'Show Text in Icons' option in [this settings window](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tFNP5.png) ), but now does not seem to be a feature...